# Python if with 'or 'and' 'not' all at the same time legal?

Tags: python, if-statement

im getting "invalid syntax"
im trying to parse a file that has junk before and after my good data.
The header is on line 71 of every size file.
The data starts on 103 of every size file.
The end of my data is always minus 7 from line_count.

im trying to use a if statement asking to get the header on 71 start getting data at 103 but not greater than minus 7 from the end

if it is in  that range, save to a text file named test.txt

code below

```
import fileinput

import time 
filename = '1.csv'

with open(filename) as file:

    lines = file.readlines()

line_count = len(lines)
   
end = line_count - 7


print('line_count is:')
print (line_count)  

print('end is')
print (end)

time. sleep (3.0)

count = 0
filename = '1.csv'

for lines in fileinput.input([filename]):
    if count == 71 or count >= 103 and not >= end:
        print (lines),
        print(count),
        count = count + 1,
        with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(lines))
```

Comment: How do you expect `not >= end` to be legal? It's not illegal because you're combining it with `and` and `or`, it's just illegal _on its own_.

Comment: Whereas `count == 71 or count >= 103 and not count >= end` would be syntactically fine -- because `count >= end` is a valid and complete statement so `not` can be applied to it. Though for the sake of your code's readers, I'd _strongly_ suggest making your intended precedence order explicit with some parens.

Comment: As another aside unrelated to your question, right now you're completely rewriting `test.txt` _from the very beginning_ for each line you process, deleting whatever content your program wrote during previous iterations through the for loop. Surely that's not what you actually intend to do.

Comment: (also, using `for lines in` when you already have a variable named `lines` with a different types created earlier in your program is an unfortunate decision; try to avoid reusing variable names).

Comment: Separately, since `count` starts at 0, how will it ever get to 1, much less to 71 or 103? You only run `count = count + 1` when it's at least 71 already, so with your current logic, when it starts at 0 it stays at 0 forever. To avoid that, `count = count + 1` (or its terser equivalent `count += 1`) can't be inside the `if`.

Comment: (Also, if you use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) you don't need to maintain a counter explicitly at all).

Answer (score 1):

In everyday language, we can say

> if X is greater than or equal to 103 and not greater than or equal to Y

... and it's understood that X is the subject for both conditions, because that's how English works.

But that's not how python works.

This code is a syntax error

```
count >= 103 and not >= end
                    ^
                    |
                    |
because you are missing a value right here
```

You have to fully spell out both comparisons:

```
count >= 103 and not count >= end
```